# Modifying instance data while ajax submit, reverts input data

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I have the following method on my Vue instance:

```
    ajaxSubmit: function(event) {
        this.loader = true;

        var form = event.target;

        var action = form.getAttribute('action');
        var data = new FormData(form);
        var method = form.getAttribute('method').toUpperCase();

        this.$http({
            body: data,
            method: method,
            url: action
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.body.alerts) {
                response.body.alerts.forEach(function(alert) {
                    this.alerts.push(alert);
                }.bind(this));
            }

            this.loader = false;
        }, function(response) {
            // same as success callback
        });
    }
```

Let's say I have an input with a default value of "Test". If I update it to "Test111" and then submit. The value reverts to "Test". The submitted value is correct, as "Test111" gets saved to my database and also after a refresh, the input has the correct value.

I managed to narrow down the problem. I observed that it only happens if in the ajaxSubmit method I change data on the instance. For example if I delete the lines:

```
this.loader = true;
this.loader = false;
this.alerts.push(alert);
```

everything works as expected.

Also, if an input is bound to the instance via v-model, it doesn't revert its value.

So, in the end I guess I found the source of the problem, but I don't understand it, and I can't solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @craig_h It's part of a large application, but I managed to put together a stripped down fiddle which replicates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpet/v3xx02n9/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that `Vue` re-renders the input element after the submit and because you have set a `value` attribute it will always re-render with the initial value. The way to get around this is to either not have an initial value, in which case `Vue` will keep the content, or to use `v-model` and bind it to data:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="test" v-model="inputVal" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
...
data:{
  ...
  inputVal: "Test"
  ...
}
...
```

Here's your updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3xx02n9/1/

Comment: Is there no other way? I knew it works if I bind it to data, but that is not a solution, as I can't use this method universally, without knowing the fields of the underlying form. Not having an initial value is also not an option, as it is an edit form.

Comment: @IllesPeter Not totally sure where the obstacle lies, commonly we don't set the initial value in the html, but set the `data` in vue, and let vue set the value displayed for us.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 Well, the form is populated by the server-side script, and that's why there's this issue. I can now see that the nicer way would be to do this client-side, but it would be a pretty big effort at this time of the project.

Comment: @IllesPeter I think you can put the server-side vars in a global js object, like `var serverVars = {}; serverVars.someComponent.someData = '{{interpolationByServerSide}}'`, and put the js file containing vue components after the above code, and then just access them in vue code as global objects.